# SharePoint problem: opening a office 2007 document tries to open as a zip file

Tags: sharepoint, zip, office-2007

I have a number of Office 2007 documents (.pptx, .docx, .xlsx) in a SharePoint document library and when user tries to open the documents, it tries to open as a zip file. This happens to some users, but not all.

I posted this issue at https://superuser.com/questions/110211/why-office-2007-documents-open-as-a-zip-file, but I failed to mention that it was related to the Sharepoint so it got moved to the superuser.com

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This article outlines quite a number of fixes for this common problem:

http://windowsnerd.com/2009/04/17/xlsx-and-docx-are-being-saved-as-a-zip-file-in-explorer/

For me, it was a configuration with IIS (having to set the correct MIME types for those extensions)